# How to create a random matrix?

Tags: python, for-loop, random, matrix

I want create a random matrix like [[[100, 50, 25], [22, 75, 195]]]

My code is

```
n = 1
r = 2
e = 3

sup = []

for i in range(n):
    sup1 = []
    for c in range(r):
       sup0 = list (random.randint (200, 0, e))
       sup1.append (sup0)
    sup.append (sup1)    

print sup
```

but python give me error.

Comment: Can you provide your full Traceback?

Comment: probably from using 3 arguments in `random.randint` since it only takes 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to directly get the random matrix of desired size with values in a given range.

```
>>> numpy.random.randint(low = 0, high = 200, size=(2, 4))
array([[ 75,  21, 132,  90],
       [112,  11, 104, 114]])

>>> r = 2
>>> n = 1
>>> numpy.random.randint(low = 0, high = 200, size=(r, n))
array([[94],
       [51]])
```

[More details](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

Answer (score 2):

This should work (No idea what `e` does):

```
sup = [[random.randint(0, 200) for _ in range(r)] for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: If you really need optimization, `itertools.repeat()` may be faster for large arrays because it doesn't manufacture integer objects for each loop.